# Is it true that $ker(f\times f')=kerf\times kerf'$ and $\#coker(f\times f')=\#coker(f)\times \#coker(f')$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism, products

Let $A,B,C,D$ be groups.
Let $f:A\to B$ and $f':C\to D$ be a group homomorphism.
Let $f\times f': A\times C\to B\times D$ be a homomorphism given by $(a,c)\to (f(a),f'(c))$.

Is it true that  $ker(f\times f')=kerf\times kerf'$ and $\#coker(f\times f')=\#coker(f)\times \#coker(f')$ ?

I think this is clear because  $ker(f\times f')=\{(a,b)\in A\times C\mid f(a)=0, f(b)=0\}=kerf\times kerf'$ and $im(f\times f')=\{(f(a),f(c))\mid (a, b)\in A\times C\}=imf\times imf'$.

I think this is almost definition, but I have never seen this statement in any text books, so I don't have confident.

Comment: Ya both equality you proved are correct.

Comment: You have some typos in the proofs. Look for f where it should be f'. And look at the variable names.

Comment: The cokernels are only defined for abelian groups, right? For the cokernels you also have an isomorphism, so the amount of elements is a corollary.

Comment: You're right. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg.   Then, is there a exact sequence $0\to ker(f\times f')\to A\times C \to B\times D \to Coker(f\times f')\to 0$ ?

Comment: This is true for every homomorphism of abelian groups.